# Order of ArrayList changes when updating from Firestore Database

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

**Problem:** My list items display in the wrong order. This happens when I close the fragment and re-open it. It then displays all the "sent messages" first, and then the received messages after. However, when I'm in writing the messages, they appear in the correct order. It's only when I close the fragment/activity and re-open it that the order has changed.

I call the `getMessages` method in my `on-create` method for opening the fragment containing the view.

**What I've tried:**

- Using the Firestore `orderby` method (both with String and TimeStamp)
- Using the simpler Firestore Snapshot Listener

**Question:**

- How do I best use the Firestore Snapshot Listener with a RecyclerView and maintain the order of the items correctly?

**Here is my main "getMessages" method:**

```
public void getLiveChatMessages(final ArrayList<ChatConversationMessage> messageArrayList, final ChatConversationAdapter adapter, final String matchClicked) {

    final String userID = onboardingFirebaseUser.returnCurrentUserId();

    final CollectionReference messagesCollectionRef = db.collection("users")
            .document(userID)
            .collection("matches")
            .document(matchClicked)
            .collection("messages");

    messagesCollectionRef
            .orderBy("TimeStamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                                                         @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                                         if (e != null) {
                                             Log.w(TAG, "listen:error", e);
                                             return;
                                         }


                                         for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : value) {
                                             if (doc.get("Message") != null) {

                                                 if (doc.get("Message") != null && doc.get("From user with ID").equals(userID)) {
                                                     String message = doc.getString("Message");

                                                     messageArrayList.add(new ChatConversationMessage(message));
                                                     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Ensures messages are visible immediately

                                                 } else if (doc.get("Message") != null) {
                                                     final String message = doc.getString("Message");

                                                     DocumentReference matchRef = db.collection("users")
                                                             .document(userID)
                                                             .collection("matches")
                                                             .document(matchClicked);

                                                     matchRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                                         @Override
                                                         public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                                             if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                 DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                                                                 if (document.exists()) {
                                                                     imageReference = storageReference.child(document.getString("profileImg"));
                                                                     messageArrayList.add(new ChatConversationMessage(message, imageReference));
                                                                     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Ensures messages are visible immediately

                                                                 } else {
                                                                     Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                                                                 }
                                                             } else {
                                                                 Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                                                             }
                                                         }
                                                     });

                                                 }
                                             }
                                         }
                                     }
                                 });}}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo Database structure added

Comment: Please add it as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo added :-)

Comment: Which one of the queries you say that it does not maintain the order?

Comment: @AlexMamo when I write the messages, it puts them in the correct order. But when I exit the fragment displaying the messages and re-open it, it changes the order of the list items

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm wondering if the Adapter for the RecyclerView is changing the order. Because it's placing all the list-items of a certain type before the other ones every time.

Comment: It might but it depends on how you have created it.

Comment: @AlexMamo I can't figure it out. I added the RecyclerView adapter to the code. Would be super thankful if you took a look at it!

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot see the reason. Maybe when you are binding those views. If you are interested, here you can find a tutorial on how to can create a complete and functional [Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb) that preserves the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I've found the problem.

I was calling a the get-method on a new reference within the snapshot listener. When you do this, it impacts the order of the items in your ArrayList.

To solve it, ensure that all the items you need from Firestore to create your ArrayList is stored in the same location as fields on each document (and not in two different locations). That way, you don't need to use a separate get-method on a new reference within a snapshot listener. This also keeps client-side code cleaner. For future Googlers, here is how I restructured my method:

```
messagesCollectionRef
            .orderBy("TimeStamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                                    @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "listen:error", e);
                        return;
                    }

                    for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                        switch (dc.getType()) {
                            case ADDED:
                                Log.d(TAG, "New message added" + dc.getDocument().getData());

                                if (dc.getDocument().get("Message") != null && dc.getDocument().get("From user with ID").equals(userID)) {
                                    String message = dc.getDocument().getString("Message");
                                    messageArrayList.add(new ChatConversationMessage(CURRENTUSER, message, null));
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }

                                if (dc.getDocument().get("Message") != null && dc.getDocument().get("From user with ID").equals(matchClicked)) {
                                    String message = dc.getDocument().getString("Message");
                                    imageReference = storageReference.child(dc.getDocument().getString("profileImg"));
                                    messageArrayList.add(new ChatConversationMessage(OTHERUSER, message, imageReference));
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                                break;
                            case MODIFIED:
                                break;
                            case REMOVED:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

As you can see, I've now stored the imageReference String within each message doc in Firestore, and it can be retrieved in the same way I retrieve all the other data I need to make an addition to my ArrayList. The major code change you need to do is where you write your data to the cloud (ie. write/set Firestore docs). That's where you'll need to make sure that everything is added as field values to your doc, so you don't need to get it in separate locations. Good luck!